# What privileges do Trusted Users have that 10K+ users don't?

Tags: support, reputation, users, privileges, trusted-user

What is the difference between the privileges of *Trusted Users* (20K+) and *10K+* (<20K) users?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[15k users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions) can protect questions.

At [20k users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) can also

> - Vote to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Vote to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)
> - Edit all tag wikis on the site

For the latest information, you can always check the [trusted user privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), the [10k user privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) and all the privilege pages in between them.